# How to bind a C1FlexGrid to a SQL Server DB Table in such a form that, when I change a cell, it will be updated in the DB

Tags: sql-server, connection-string, c1flexgrid

Is it possible to link C1FlexGrid to a table in a SQL Server database so that when I change the value of a cell, the corresponding value in the database is immediately updated? In the OCX version of ComponentOne FlexGrid, it's straightforward, but in the non-OCX version, I can't find a way to do it. Thank you very much for your kind support.